# Gaming/Animation Tutorials for c++ and Windows Forms!

Tags: c++-cli

I'm having trouble finding some gaming/animation tutorial for c++ and windows form.
I've been told (online) by many people to use gamedev.net, which i did, but unfortunately i could not find the information that i need :(

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for either a simple games (like snake or pong) or of simple animation in Windows Forms using C++ ( not C# )? If so, **please** let me know!

Looking forward to a reply,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Allegro in C++ or mixed C++\CLI.

see [here](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/readme.html).